# Console.ReadKey(); and Switch statement - using letters

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a program in C# that basically functions based on the key a user presses (ex. X = Quit, D = Disconnect, etc;) by using Console.ReadKey(); in c#

The problem I'm running into is how to use the ReadKey info in a Switch statement.. Can someone help please? The code is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Switch_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome. Please enter your command: ");
            string chinput;
            int input;
            bool activated = false;
            input = Console.ReadKey();
            chinput = Convert.ToChar(input);
            switch (chinput)
            {
                case 'x':
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You pressed x...");
                        break;
                    }
                case 'y':
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You pressed y..");
                        break;
                    }
                case 'd':
                    {
                        if (activated != true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Please activate first!");
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Active..");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                case 'a':
                    {
                        if (activated != true)
                        {
                            activated = true;
                            Console.WriteLine("Activating..");
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            activated = false;
                            Console.WriteLine("Deactivating.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Unknown Command.");
                    break;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I know that's probably really wrong but I originally started with Console.ReadLine(); , the only difference is I want it to activate a function when you press a single key rather than having to hit enter or being able to type in different keys. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28):

First of all, `Convert.ToChar()` doesn't work on `ConsoleKeyInfo` structure, so that's why you have problems, this conversion will throw an Exception.

You don't have to convert your key to character, instead, you can switch on `.Key` property, which is an enumerable that contains every key:

```
var input = Console.ReadKey();

switch (input.Key) //Switch on Key enum
{
    case ConsoleKey.X:
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.Y:
        break;
}
```

Edit:

1. You can also use `input.KeyChar` to get what you tried first - character, then you can switch on it if you want to, but it's harded to switch on different keys like arrows etc.
2. If you care if letter is capital/small, you can use `.KeyChar` or use `.Key` with `.Modifiers` to check if shift key was pressed when user typed the letter

Answer (score 15):

You can simply take input as:

```
char input=Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

using Console.ReadKey() returns a type of a struct ConsoleKeyInfo. so you need to recieve the return in a variable from this type.
Then switch on the Key enumrator, that has all characters.

```
 ConsoleKeyInfo chinput = Console.ReadKey();

        switch (chinput.Key)
        {
            case ConsoleKey.X:

                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed x...");
                    break;
                }
            case ConsoleKey.Y:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You pressed y..");
                    break;
                }
            case ConsoleKey.D:
                {
                    if (activated != true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please activate first!");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Active..");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            case ConsoleKey.A:
                {
                    if (activated != true)
                    {
                        activated = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("Activating..");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        activated = false;
                        Console.WriteLine("Deactivating.");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown Command.");
                break;
        }
```