# C# calculator user input issue

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a C# calculator for a class, but when I try to use it it always returns blatantly wrong answers, like 1+3 = 100, or rounding down the decimal 2.33 to 50. It also crashes after the first input every time, which makes me think that its reading when i press enter for some reason, but I've looked and can't find documentation on any issue like that. Thanks in advance.

'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace calculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //set label for finished functions to return to
            start:
            System.Console.WriteLine("choose from one of the following calculator choices");
            System.Console.WriteLine("1: whole number");
            System.Console.WriteLine("2: addition");
            System.Console.WriteLine("3: sine");
            System.Console.WriteLine("4: cosine");
            System.Console.WriteLine("5: absolue value");
            System.Console.WriteLine("6: quit");
            int optionSelect = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
            switch (optionSelect)
            {
                
                case 1:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("whole number");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("give a decimal");
                    decimal temp = System.Console.Read();
                    System.Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(temp));
                    goto start;
                case 2:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("addition");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("first int");
                    int add1 = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadKey());
                    System.Console.WriteLine("second int");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int add2 = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.Read());
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    int answer = add1+add2;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("the answer is " + answer);
                    goto start;
                case 3:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("sine");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("enter your angle in radians");
                    double numSin = Console.Read();
                    System.Console.WriteLine(Math.Sin(numSin));
                    goto start;
                case 4:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("cosine");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("enter your angle in radians");
                    double numCos = Console.Read();
                    System.Console.WriteLine(Math.Cos(numCos));
                    goto start;
                case 5:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("absolute value");
                    System.Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
                    double num = Convert.ToDouble(Console.Read());
                    System.Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(num));
                    goto start;
                case 6:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("shutting down...");
                    goto start;
                default:
                    System.Console.WriteLine("invalid input");
                    goto start;

            }
            
            
            
        }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Hint: look at the documentation for `Console.Read()`. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong integer output on Console.Read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050026/wrong-integer-output-on-console-read)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.ReadKey(); and Switch statement - using letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989647/console-readkey-and-switch-statement-using-letters)

Comment: You also have the same issue with ReadKey. You're also expecting user input and then throwing it away (calls to ReadLine that you don't do anything with). And don't use Convert.ToInt32. You'll have better luck (and your mistake will become more apparent ) if you use int.Parse/int.TryParse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are multiple problems in your code.

`Console.Read` will return the corresponding ASCII code for the first character that you enter. Here is a link with the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

So if you put in the console 0 is not actually 0 but the corespondent value for 0 in the ASCII table. 0=48, 1=49, 2=50 ... 9 = 50.

If you put multiple characters only the first one will be processed by `Console.Read`.

To fix your problem you could use as you did in the begging :

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
```

and after that, you can convert that line to whatever you need like `decimal x = Convert.ToDecimal(line)`. or `int x = Convert.ToInt32(line)`

Also please try to change that `goto` logic into a `while`.